# Can not install react-router but need browser back button functionality

Tags: reactjs

Need to navigate back with **browser back button**, but can not do it as not possible to install `react-router`. What to do?

Comment: You need way more information than this. What do you even mean by navigate if you're not using react router? Where does the back button take you when you click it right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is then to use `history.push` for adding new URLs and having back button working in the browser.

Like: `history.push({}, "", "/next-route")`